# Update url in tab and title

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to update a tab over the Id. This is working. After it, I want to set the title of the tab. The Code below is not working. For a short time the title is shown, but then it gets overwritten with the updated site...

```
    chrome.tabs.update(globalData.bbId, {url: 'MYURL'}, function (){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(globalData.bbId, {code: 'document.title = "Test"'});
    });
```

Its possible to set the title easily?

thanks

Comment: Use MutationObserver targeted at `document.head` to and re-assign `document.title` if it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's update tab API callback is called when the new URL is in started to load and not when the loading is completed, you can check that in the callback as well.

// basic query.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: 'http://facebook.com'}, (tab) => { 
        console.log(tab.status); // loading
    })
})
```

After "loading" status "completed" status comes when url is completely loaded and it's where your Title is getting overwritten. And you have no callback to catch completed state.

So, you can get your work done by below options :-

Option 1 - Use setTimeout() and set expected time when you think reload will be done. I have set it to 3 seconds here.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, (tabs) => {
    chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: 'http://facebook.com'}, (tab) => { 
        setTimeout(() => { chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "document.title = 'New Title'"}) }, 3000);
    })
})
```

Option 2 - You can listen to Tab Updated Event like

```
let tabUpdateHandler = (tabId, {url: updatedUrl, status}, tab) => {
    if (updatedUrl && status = 'completed') {
        // set your new title here
    }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(tabUpdateHandler);
```

Both the options can set your Title correctly.
Happy Coding.